# Extracting Metadata of Lotus Notes Applications Using Notes Java API?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am looking for extracting metadata about Notes Applications on a Domino server using Java Notes API. I tried reading the list of applications/databases from catalog.nsf file.
  But catalog.nsf does not have new Applications that are created based on a existing template.

So From where can I get the list of applications that are existing on a Domino Server? Will the new Applications be added to catalog? If not how to make them to be added in the catalog?

Any help or Ideas will be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Srinivas

Answer (score 4):

So if you want to do this in Java  If the catalog.nsf is not upto date, then you can also try the dbdirectory class, look ==>[here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESDBDIRECTORY_CLASS_JAVA.html).

This should have an example to give you an idea how to read through all database on the server. If the Domino server is not registering new applications then catalog process is not running. You can load it by simply type "load catalog" at the console. More details ==>[here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_MANAGING_THE_DATABASE_CATALOG_OVERVIEW.html).

There can still be other issues, but will wait for your response.

Comment: I just followed the above link, and it is going to a page that talks about the dircat process.  But dircat does not maintain the Database Catalog.  Dircat maintains Directory Catalog databases, which contain Person docs that are copied from multiple Domino Directory databases.  It is the "catalog" process that maintains the Database Catalog.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up... I have update the second link and corrected the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a "Server Fault" answer, but in the Domino Directory, you can turn on the Domain Catalog server task for a server in your domain, and that server will populate (and keep updated) the catalog.nsf file, which will then replicate across your domain.

So just enable that task within the server document, or go to the domino console and type **load catalog**